# What to chose ArgumentNullException or NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a small lib of method extensions.

For example we have extension method

```
public static T GetRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

Which exception **ArgumentNullException** or **NullReferenceException** will be the clearest for case when collection is null? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the argument which is null, so you should throw an `ArgumentNullException`. You should basically never throw `NullReferenceException` directly - it should only get thrown (automatically) when you try to dereference a null value.

The fact that you're writing an extension method doesn't change the fact that really it's a static method and `collection` is a parameter.

As usual, specify the name of the parameter which is null, using `nameof` if you're using C# 6:

```
public static T GetRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
    }
    ...
}
```

(As an aside, check out [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), which may well have most of your methods already...)

Comment: MoreLINQ looks great, thanks)

Answer (score 3):

You should never throw `NullReferenceException`. This exception is thrown by the framework if you try to access an object that has the value `null`.

Se you need to throw `ArgumentNullException` like this:

```
public static T GetRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if(collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    //...
}
```